# Strange compiler optimization while reading binary file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-optimization

I'm using vs2008 win xp x32 and using some function for reading binary file and then put some statistics in other txt file:

Here is function:

Stange behaviour happens then I add line

```
ofstream filestr(pathname,ios::out);
```

function runs about 3 times faster (21 sec vs 75 sec on ~250Mb file) WTF?

```
__int64 ReadBinaryFile(const char* fileName)
{
    char* pathname= "Stats.txt";
    ofstream filestr(pathname,ios::out); //comment/uncomment this line

    FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if(f != NULL)
    {
        if( _fseeki64(f,0,SEEK_END) != 0)   // 0 == success
            return 0;
        __int64 file_size = _ftelli64(f);
        if (file_size == 0)
            return 0;
        if( _fseeki64(f,0,SEEK_SET) != 0)   // 0 == success
            return 0;

        while( !feof( f ) )
        {
            unsigned char temp[2];
            if(fread(temp,sizeof(unsigned char),2,f)!=2)
                break;
            int skip_bytes= LowHighByte(temp[0],temp[1]); //skip n bytes

            if (skip_bytes==0)
                break;

            if(fread(temp,sizeof(unsigned char),2,f)!=2)
                break;
            int marker= LowHighByte(temp[0],temp[1]);

            int sz= skip_bytes-4;
            unsigned char* data= new unsigned char[sz];
            if(fread(data,sizeof(unsigned char),sz,f)!= sz )
                break;

            delete[] data;
        }

        filestr.close();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, the difference happens when you just open the file ? I mean, from what it appears in the code you are just opening and closing the stream. Is this intended ?

Comment: This will leak memory if it hits the last `break;` in the `while` loop.

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou Yes, surprisingly when I open the stream function runs faster. I use clock() to measure entire ReadBinaryFile function time execution.

Comment: @crashmstr  thanks. I fixed it, but performance is still the same.

Comment: @mrgloom My comment was more of a side note, but the only thing I could think of would be something with how the C++ and C I/O interact. Have you tried just doing this with C++ I/O completely and tested that?

Comment: *Where* have you inserted that line, and when does it execute relative to your `ReadBinaryFile` function?

Comment: If the fstream API is somehow faster on MSVC2008 than stdio, the Windows CRT could feasibly use fstream in the stdio implementation if it had been previously used. However, any reason why fstream would be faster than stdio is beyond me. Have you tried using fopen to open the text file, and seeing if that makes it slow again? If that's the case, switching to purely using fstream could be your best bet.

Comment: You are reading the data file in very small chunks.  That will be inefficient without buffering, or with too little buffering. I speculate that perhaps I/O buffering is initially disabled, but that the `ofstream` constructor globally enables it, or else that the `ofstream` constructor mucks with the default I/O buffer size.

Comment: @crashmstr yes I tested C++ I/O with streams and it was as fast as when I add this line of code `ofstream filestr(pathname,ios::out);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin this line inside ReadBinaryFile function as shown in code snippet (comment/uncomment line).

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, it can be some compiler optimisations or OS buffering, but I want to understand why I get such performance in detail.

Comment: If you want to understand the behaviour you observe then you're going to need to analyze it.  The point you should be taking from all the comments is that the performance difference cannot be explained based on your code alone.  As such, moreover, it is likely specific to your C++ implementation.  For the most part, we have been giving you ideas of things to consider in such an analysis.